# Can I detect a jscript window.close event in a browser control hosted in a Windows form?

Tags: c#, javascript

My client has a requirement to display a "splash" screen when users log on.  Currently my client uses a Windows Application that instantiates a **System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser** class to host a web page but, for various reasons, this is unsuitable.

My client has asked me to create a chrome-free modal Windows form that will contain a browser control which will host the web page.  This page consists of a message and two buttons:  "Yes" (navigates to another URL) and "No" (closes the browser).

In the current (unsatisfactory) incarnation, the "No" button calls a javascript function that includes

```
window.close();
```

This works fine at the moment, but obviously if (in the new incarnation) the web page is hosted inside a browser control inside a Windows Form, then the window.close will not automatically bubble up to the Windows Form.

So, is there any way for the Windows Form to "detect" the window.close event which occurs in the browser control?

I hope the foregoing is clear.

Many thanks

Edward

Comment: You could add a poller to the Windows Form to check a webpage DOM variable. Add some javascript to set a value when the No button is clicked and profit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling window.close call your external C# function from javascript, something like this

```
window.external.CloseWindow
```

and set your object as scripting

```
webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
```

your C# class should have CloseWindow function

or override window.close like

```
window.close=function() { window.external.CloseWindow(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

With some extra digging Sudhakar B's answer works.  I had to add

```
   [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
```

to decorate the class.